# Apprequest: get all people that invited specific users / getting user_id of user who opens notification

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made a referral system, where a user can invite his friend to the app.

I'd like to see which user opens the notification on the Facebook. Is this possible? This way, I can figure out who have also invited this user, and let him know that "XXX other friends have also invited him"

The URL on Facebook is:

`fb_source=notification&request_ids=THE_REQUEST_ID&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request`

I know I can simply look up the request_id, but this way, I only know the ONE user who have invited, and not all the others.

Comment: Then you’ll have to save the id of the inviting user at the time they _make_ the request.

Comment: Yeah? Using the data attribute or?

Comment: That would be one possibility, yes. The alternative would be to save the id of the current user of your app and the request ids you get back from the dialog into your own database, but using the data attribute is probably easier.

Comment: OK Thanks. I already save the friend ids AND the request ids the user has invited, to my database. However, I don't see a solution to figure out EXACTLUY which user opens the notification. I can find out WHO invited, but not down to the actal user. Using the object_id/data attribute will only work for single friend invite, as the data/object will be the same for ALL invited friends. Do you have any ideas @CBroe?

Comment: `request_ids` should be a comma-separated list of request ids, if the user is acting on one of multiple requests of the same kind.

Comment: It is not :( Looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uef1lqr2fr937jo/Screenshot%202014-03-28%2015.15.15.png

Comment: That looks more like the return data of the Requests dialog …

Comment: Yeah and it is. What else do you mean?

Comment: That what you were talking about from the beginning …? The `request_ids` parameter passed to your app when a user acts on requests.

Comment: Yes. But this way I cannot identify who opens the app. I want to check if the user who opens the notification has been invited by other users. But before I can figure out if he have been invited by other users, I have to figure out who he is (i.e. his facebook user id)

Comment: Well then have them log in.

Comment: That is what I would like to incentivize them to do, by telling how many of their friends invited him.